# Return Row 1 of Column where match was found

Tags: vba, excel-2016

On my workbook, a command button is looping through every cell in column A, D, G and J.
If the cell contains a blue border, it's searching for its match on another workbook.
If that match is found, it's placing the cell value from original workbook to the 2nd workbook, in the next column of where the match was found.

I have 2 if statements checking if the next column is empty, and if it is then put the value there, if not then find the next empty cell in that row and put there.

I'm trying to return the first row (A1, D1, G1, or J1) from the original workbook, into the adjacent column of the newly placed values on the 2nd workbook.

Example:

- On Workbook 1, the name "John Doe" and "Jane Doe" have a blue border in Column A.
- On Workbook 2, "John Doe" was found in Column A, Row 123 and "Jane Doe" was found in Column A, Row 250.
- The macro places "John Doe" in Column B, Row 123 and "Jane Doe" in Column B, Row 250 (assuming that cell in B123 and B250 are empty).

From Workbook 1, I want to also place the cell value in A1 - Into Workbook 2: Column C, Row 123 and 250.

But I want to do this for Columns A D G J simultaneously (rr3dest in my below code is what I'm trying to set this value to, I know it's not set to anything right now).

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim testWS As Worksheet
Dim testRange As Range, idCella As Range
Dim alastRow2 As Long, resultM As Integer
Dim rr2dest As Range, rr3dest As Range

Set testWS = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("October")                                       'set the 2nd workbook as testWS
Set testRange = testWS.Columns(1)                                                                                            'searching only column A on testWS (2nd workbook)
alastRow2 = Worksheets("Reruns To Pull").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                   'find last row in column A that has data on current workbook
dlastRow2 = Worksheets("Reruns To Pull").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
glastrow2 = Worksheets("Reruns To Pull").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
jlastrow2 = Worksheets("Reruns To Pull").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row


For Each idCella In Worksheets("Reruns To Pull").Range("A1:A" & alastRow2 & ",D1:D" & dlastRow2 & ",G1:G" & glastrow2 & ",J1:J" & jlastrow2).Cells                'for each cell in Column A on current workbook (eventually I want to loop through Column A, D, G, J.  All will be variable ranges)

        If idCella.Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 192) Then                                                 'On current workbook, if cells in Col A borders.color = blue then

            If Not IsError(Application.Match(idCella.Value, testRange, 0)) Then                                      'find exact match on Test.xlsx (2nd workbook) and store in variable resultM
                resultM = (Application.Match(idCella.Value, testRange, 0))
                                                                                       
            If IsEmpty(testWS.Range("A" & CStr(resultM)).Offset(0, 1)) Then                         ' if resultM.offset(0,1) is empty then set destination to .offset(0,1)
                Set rr2dest = testWS.Range("A" & CStr(resultM)).Offset(0, 1)
                    rr2dest.Value = idCella.Value
                    rr2dest.Interior.Color = idCella.Interior.Color
                    rr2dest.Borders.Color = idCella.Borders.Color
                    rr2dest.Borders.Weight = idCella.Borders.Weight
                Set rr3dest = testWS.Range("A" & CStr(resultM)).Offset(0, 2)
                    
            ElseIf Not IsEmpty(testWS.Range("A" & CStr(resultM)).Offset(0, 1)) Then                 ' if resultM.offset(0,1) is not empty then set destination to .end(xltoright).offset(0,1)
                Set rr2dest = testWS.Range("A" & CStr(resultM)).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
                    rr2dest.Value = idCella.Value
                    rr2dest.Interior.Color = idCella.Interior.Color
                    rr2dest.Borders.Color = idCella.Borders.Color
                    rr2dest.Borders.Weight = idCella.Borders.Weight
                End If
            End If
        End If
    
Next idCella

    testWS.Range("A2:M80").WrapText = True
    testWS.Columns("A:M").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    testWS.Columns("A:M").VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled but not tested:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim testWS As Worksheet, pullWS As Worksheet
    Dim testRange As Range, idCella As Range
    
    Dim arrSourceCols, col, v, m, c As Range
    
    Set testWS = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("October")   'set the 2nd workbook as testWS
    Set testRange = testWS.Columns(1)                           'searching only column A on testWS (2nd workbook)
    
    Set pullWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reruns To Pull")
    
    arrSourceCols = Array("A", "D", "G", "J") 'columns to be scanned and matched
    
    For Each col In arrSourceCols   'loop source columns
        For Each idCella In pullWS.Range(pullWS.Cells(1, col), _
                                         pullWS.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp)).Cells
            If idCella.Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 192) Then
                v = idCella.Value                      'value to look for
                m = Application.Match(v, testRange, 0) 'match?
                If Not IsError(m) Then
                    Set c = testWS.Cells(m, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) 'get empty cell
                    c.Value = v                                       'put the matched value
                    CopyFormats idCella, c                            'transfer formatting
                    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = pullWS.Cells(1, col).Value 'put the header from the column
                End If  'matched
            End If      'blue borders
        Next idCella
    Next col

    testWS.Range("A2:M80").WrapText = True
    testWS.Columns("A:M").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    testWS.Columns("A:M").VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
    
End Sub

Sub CopyFormats(cFrom As Range, cTo As Range)
    With cTo
        .Interior.Color = cFrom.Interior.Color
        .Borders.Color = cFrom.Borders.Color
        .Borders.Weight = cFrom.Borders.Weight
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are a wizard, Mr. Tim Williams.  You always take all my redundant code and condense it to nothing, but is very much appreciated nonetheless.  It does work, but it looks like it's looping through the same column multiple times and adding the different headers for the remaining columns.  I'll comment again with the description.

Comment: The info under Column D, exports correctly (I changed ```Set c = testWS.Cells(m, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0)``` to offset(0,1)) and puts the D1 header into the next column.  But once it finishes the rest of Column D it loops back through and puts the same information only with the header of Column G to the right.  And the same for Column J.

Is there a simple way to have it loop through each column at a time IE through Col D, find all blue borders, place them next to the match and then put Col D header just for those matches, and so on

Comment: This was sort of the issue I was running into with my original code.  I wasn't sure how to do this without writing a completely separate loop for each column. 

IE. applying the headers to the information only found under that column.  

Realizing now that would have been a better explanation in my initial post, but like I said, my brain is at about 1/8 capacity right now :)

Comment: I messed up the line `For Each idCella In ...` - fixed that and the other `Offset()` typo you mentioned

Comment: I swear, I owe you like 40 beers.  Thank you so much!